# CSS/alignment issues when populating page with d3.js charts

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I don't understand why there is empty space between the left column (highlighed in image) and the header. This only happens when i populate the middle column with chart. Looking at chrome developer i don't understand what i am missing. Here is a snippet of the code. I tried adding margin and padding both to the bottom of the image on left column but that didn't help. What am i missing?

```
<body style="padding-left: 5px;">
<div id="header" style="width: 960px; height: 100px; background-color: #F5F5F5">
    <p>Bubble Inc</p>
</div>
<div id="container" style="width: 1100px; height: 1000px"">
    <div id="leftCol" style="width: 225px; display: inline-block; margin-bottom: 50px; padding-bottom: 30px;"></div>
    <div id="midCol" style="width: 600px; display: inline-block;"></div>
    <div id="rightCol" style="width: 225px; display: inline-block;"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
```

[image: CSS & D3.js]

Comment: what actually you want to do ?

Comment: do u need all those three `divs` to be in same line?

Comment: @XTG, i want the image on the left and right column to be placed higher. when i add padding to bottom, it does not move it up.

Comment: @SakthiKumar, yes i want them to be on one line. They are sections within the page that are next to each other. if i dont make them inline they will go on seperate lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the big charts drag the smaller down, because you have **no vertical alignment rule**. I added a big place holder chart (id: `bigContent`) to your code to show the effect:

```
<style>
    #leftCol  { background-color: red   }
    #rightCol { background-color: green }
    #midCol   { background-color: blue  }
    #bigContent { height: 200px;}
</style>
<div id="header"    style="width: 960px; height: 100px; background-color: yellow"><p>Bubble Inc</p></div>
<div id="container" style="width: 1100px; height: 1000px">
    <div id="leftCol"  style="width: 225px; display: inline-block;">A</div>
    <div id="midCol"   style="width: 600px; display: inline-block;">
        <div id="bigContent">Biiig Content</div>
    </div>
    <div id="rightCol" style="width: 225px; display: inline-block;">C</div>
</div>
```

You can **fix the problem** by adding a vertical alignment rule to the `style` section.

```
    #container>div { vertical-align: top; }
```